# There is a given element say N. How to modify Binary Search to find greatest element in a sorted vector which smaller than N

Tags: c++, vector, binary-search, std

For example:
Let us have a sorted vector with elements: `[1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10, 11, 13]`
And we have an element `N = 5`

I want output as:

```
4
```

Since 4 is the greatest element smaller than N.

I want to modify **Binary Search** to get the answer

Comment: What do you mean by "modify BinarySearch"? The standard library has a function that does exactly this.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#searching-sorted-lists

Comment: I want a solution in c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would you want to happen if there is an element that equals `N` in the vector?

I would use `std::lower_bound` (or `std::upper_bound` depending on the answer to the above question). It runs in logarithmic time which means it's probably using binary search under the hood.

```
std::optional<int> find_first_less_than(int n, std::vector<int> data) {
    // things must be sorted before processing
    std::sort(data.begin(), data.end());

    auto it = std::lower_bound(data.begin(), data.end(), n);

    // if all of the elements are above N, we'll return nullopt
    if (it == data.begin()) return std::nullopt;

    return *std::prev(it);
}
```

Comment: I will perform a binary search to check if there is an element that equals N in vector.